# Programattically Imposing Size and Type Restriction on a List Attachment

Tags: 2010, list, development, attachments, visual-studio-2012

I'm using the code below to allow users to upload files as attachments to items in a SharePoint (2010) List.

How can I add type and size restrictions to the attachment, for example, if I wanted the attachments to succeed only if the file was a .JPG under 5MB in size?

```
<input type="file" runat="server" id="fuUploadFile" />
<asp:Button ID="btnUpload" runat="server" Text="Upload" OnClick="btnUpload_Click" />
```

Code behind:

Code behind

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

```
protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;
    SPList lst = web.Lists["SampleList"];
    SPListItem item = lst.Items.GetItemById(1);
    SPAttachmentCollection attachments = item.Attachments;
    attachments.Add(fuUploadFile.PostedFile.FileName, ReadStream(fuUploadFile.PostedFile.InputStream));
    item.Update();
}
public static byte[] ReadStream(Stream input)
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[16 * 1024];
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        int read;
        while ((read = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following example code for your reference.

```
<p>
    <asp:Label ID="userMessage" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
</p>
<p>
    <asp:FileUpload ID="fuUploadFile" runat="server" />
    <asp:Button ID="btnUpload" runat="server" Text="Upload" OnClick="btnUpload_Click" />
</p>
```

**Code behind**:

```
protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!fuUploadFile.HasFile)
    {
        userMessage.Text = "Please select a file before clicking upload.";
        return;
    }
    //Check the file is less than 5MB
    int fileSize = fuUploadFile.PostedFile.ContentLength;
    if (fileSize > 5000000)
    {
        userMessage.Text += String.Format("File Size Exceeds 5MB. Choose a smaller file.");
        return;
    }

    String imageFileExtension = Path.GetExtension(fuUploadFile.FileName);
    //Check the user has selected a jpg image
    if (imageFileExtension == null || imageFileExtension.ToLower() != ".jpg")
    {
        userMessage.Text += "The file you have selected is not in the right format. Please use a jpg image.";
        return;
    }
    userMessage.Text = "";
    SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;
    SPList lst = web.Lists["SampleList"];
    SPListItem item = lst.Items.GetItemById(1);
    SPAttachmentCollection attachments = item.Attachments;
    attachments.Add(fuUploadFile.PostedFile.FileName, ReadStream(fuUploadFile.PostedFile.InputStream));
    item.Update();
}
public static byte[] ReadStream(Stream input)
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[16 * 1024];
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        int read;
        while ((read = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Refer to: [SharePoint: Build a Webpart to Resize and Upload Images to a Picture Library](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/17739.sharepoint-build-a-webpart-to-resize-and-upload-images-to-a-picture-library.aspx)